# Passing value of a variable to another variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a function that will output fibonacci numbers. This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
a1=0;
a2=1;
echo "Vnesi n"
read n
echo $a1
echo $a2
for ((i = 1; i <= $n; i++)) do
    a3=$(($a1+$a2))
    echo $a3
    $a1=$a2
    $a2=$a3
done
```

When I run it, it gets to to line 10 (echo $a3) and then outputs an error:

```
1
0
1
1
./fib.sh: line 11: 0=1: command not found
./fib.sh: line 12: 1=1: command not found
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to pass value from a2 to a1 and value from a3 to a2. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first variable assignments are correct:

```
a1=0
a2=1
```

The second ones incorrectly prefix the left-hand side with a dollar sign:

```
$a1=$a2   # Should be a1=$a2
$a2=$a3   # Should be a2=$a3
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
    $a1=$a2
    $a2=$a3
```

with

```
    a1=$a2
    a2=$a3
```

Answer (score 0):

a1=$a2

not $a1

otherwise the left side is evaluated and the value (0 or whatever) is used